# Receiving "role" and/or "affiliation" with message in SleekXMPP

Tags: python, xmpp, bots

Apologies for the amateur question. I'm just learning Python and I'm fumbling around this XMPP bot script using XMPP.

I have a bot built using the MUC bot example from SleekXMPP: http://sleekxmpp.com/getting_started/muc.html

Where my bot differs from the example is my script creates a SQLite database and on each group_message event, parses the XML to retrieve the nick and message body text and write it to the database with a timestamp.

Here is the part of my bot that's recording the msg output from the XMPP channel:

```
def groupchat_message(self, msg):
    if msg['type'] in ('groupchat'):
        raw = str(msg) # Save raw XML as a string in the database for debugging purposes
        timestamp = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        fromuser = str(msg['from']) # Convert "from" attribute to string so it can be split
        author = fromuser.split('/')[1] # Split "from" attribute to remove channel address leaving only nick behind
        body = msg['body']

        msginsert = [timestamp, author, body, raw] # Database input list to be handed to placeholders.

        db.execute("INSERT INTO messages VALUES (?,?,?,?)", msginsert) # "?" placeholder is REQUIRED for automatic database sanitization.
        dbconn.commit()

        print("[",timestamp,"]",author,": ",body, sep='')
    else:
        print(msg)
```

The print statements are just for debugging purposes so I can watch the messages tick by in the terminal so I know the script is running.

In the recorded information I would like to also include the user's role or affiliation in the XMPP channel so admins and moderators can be singled out. This is what I'm having trouble wrapping my head around. It seems like I should be able to do it based on the [SleekXMPP stanza docs](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki/Stanzas%3a-Presence) but I'm having trouble figuring out how I get from the message XML to the role/affiliation information.

How can I take the information provided in the message XML and get back the role and/or affiliation of the user who posted that message?

For reference, this is the raw XML output from the XMPP channel for messages:

```
<message to="username@example.com" from="channelname@channels.example.com/User Nick" id="1453" type="groupchat">
    <body>This is the message body text</body>
    <x xmlns="jabber:x:event">
        <composing />
    </x>
</message>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role/affiliation isn't included in the message, it is part of the state of the chat.

As a reminder, XMPP has three different stanzas that get send: `<message>`, which you had as an example, `<iq>`, which are used to retrieve or set things and `<presence>`, which indicates the presence of things. The role/affiliation information is included in a presence stanza. For example in the first presence stanzas your client receives to inform it of who is present in the room already, see [Example 21 from XEP-0045 (Multi-User Chat)](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#example-21). Your client also receives new presence stanzas whenever someone's nickname, role or affiliation changes or when they leave the room.

You should make sure you store this information yourself, because SleekXMPP doesn't do it for you. This can be done by creating a dictionary that stores, for every nickname, their role and one for their affiliation. On presence changes you should make sure to update this information. Then you can use those dictionaries in your message handler to log their role/affiliation.

So something like:

```
def __init__(...):
    self.roles = dict()
    self.affiliations = dict()
    self.add_event_handler(""groupchat_presence"", self.muc_presence)

...

def muc_presence(self, presence):
    nick = presence['muc']['nick']

    self.roles[nick] = presence['muc']['role']
    self.affiliations[nick] = presence['muc']['affiliation']
```

This is the general idea, you'll need to do some more work to make it handle nickname changes and people leaving the room properly.

Comment: Nick changes aren't an issue as they're not allowed on this server. By handling user quits you mean removing the information from the dictionary? I'm pretty sure I know how to do that.

Comment: Yes. Strictly speaking it wouldn't be necessary to remove them (as they'd join again before sending a message), but you'd be wasting memory if you didn't.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I got the role and affiliation logging all set up and it's working. Do you know if there's a leave event trigger in Sleek that I can use to delete the dict entries or will I have to set that up manually be detecting the leave messages?

Comment: Parts can be detected by checking whether presence['type'] == 'unavailable' in the muc_presence callback example I gave.